# jQuery trigger() right click on working after click detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simulate a right click when the user left clicks on a class called "navCog", however the JS/ JQuery code I have does not work, I've put in an alert on the click to see if it gets there, it does...

```
$(document).on("click", ".navCog", function()
{
  $(this).trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 3
   });
});
```

I did read something about I may need to create a listener first before the trigger event, but could not find out why or how?

Comment: Your code does work, just don't use alert for debugging: https://jsfiddle.net/w4o6ytd6/

Comment: Ok I see, however when the right click happens it is suppose to trigger another right click event which has a listener but it doesn’t do it?

Comment: But if I right click manually on a .navCog it will trigger the other right click event.

Comment: The click event (and `mouseup` as well) will never trigger on right click because of the context menu. You can trick it by adding the `contextmenu` event alongside the `click`. https://jsfiddle.net/w4o6ytd6/1/. And yes, if you right click manually the element, the event will trigger. If that's not what you want, you should simply use a function.